# A formula for the difference between Riemann sum and Riemann integral

Tags: integration, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

I'm looking for a formula expressing the difference between the Riemann sum and the Riemann integral. If  $S=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} f(an)$,  $I=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} dx f(x)$ and $a>0$, then I'm looking for an expression for the coefficients $c_i$  in the following formula:

$$S=I+a c_1+....+a^n c_n + O(a^{n+1})$$

where the Big $O$ notation refers to the limit $a\rightarrow 0$.

In other words, $I$ is the first approximation of $S$, while the $c_i$ give the remainder (I let the reader give hypothesis on the function $f$)

Comment: Riemann Sums converge to Riemann Integrals, so your question (at least as stated, with infinite limits), is trivial - the difference is zero.

Comment: check out  [Euler–Maclaurin_formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler–Maclaurin_formula)

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen; I think you are missing the point: the limit refers to  $O(a^{n+1})$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Ok, thank you